# Select Most Recent Date with Inner Join

Tags: sql, select, max, min

Running into a wall when trying to pull info from tables similar to those below.  Not sure how to approach this.

The results should have the most recent TRANSAMT for each ACCNUM along with NAME and address.

```
   Select A.ACCNUM, MAX(B.TRANSAMT) as BAMT, B.ADDRESS from
     From TableA A inner join TableB on A.ACCNUM = B.ACCNUM
```

This is what i have so far.  Any help would be appreciated.

TableA

```
ACCNUM    NAME        ADDRESS
00001    R. GRANT    Miami, FL
00002    B. PAUL     Dallas, TX
```

TableB

```
ACCNUM  TRANSAMT   TRANSDATE
00001    150       1/1/2015
00001    200       13/2/2015
00002    100       2/1/205
00003     50       18/2/2015
```

Comment: please tag your database engine as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `row_number` to order rows per each account number by the most recent first.

```
select accnum, amt, name, address 
from (
select A.ACCNUM, B.TRANSAMT as BAMT, B.ADDRESS,A.Name,
row_number() over(partition by a.accnum order by b.transdate desc) as rn
From TableA A 
inner join TableB on A.ACCNUM = B.ACCNUM
) t
where rn = 1;
```

Please note this will not work if you are using `MySQL`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the ANSI standard `row_number()` function in most databases.  This allows you to do conditional aggregation:

```
select a.accnum, a.name, b.amount, a.address
from tableA a left join
     (select b.*, row_number() over (partition by accnum order by transdate desc) as seqnum
      from tableB b
     ) b
     on a.accnum = b.accnum and b.seqnum = 1;
```

Note: I changed the `join` to a `left join`.  This will keep all records in `tableA`, even those with no matches.  I am not sure if that is the intention of your query.

Answer (score 0):

This one with no ROW_NUMBER():

```
with find_max as(
select acc_name,max(TRANSDATE) as TRANSDATE from talbeB group by acc_name)
select find_max.ACCNUM , A.TRANSAMT , 
find_max.TRANSDATE , B.ADDRESS,B.Name
from tableA as A
join find_max on find_max.ACCNUM=A.ACCNUM and find_max.ACCNUM=A.ACCNUM
join TableB B on A.ACCNUM = B.ACCNUM
```

First find the max date for each acc_name, the join both of tables to it.
Will work on most data bases.